# $C$ border of surface $x^{2} + y^{4} + z^{4} = 1$ and $v= (3zx^{2}, 12\sin y, x\cos z^{3} )$. Calculate $\int_{C}^{}v dt$

Tags: surfaces, parametric, parametrization, line-integrals

Let $C$ be the border of the surface $S$ with equation $x^{2} + y^{4} + z^{4} = 1$ and $v= (3zx^{2}, 12\sin y, x\cos z^{3} )$. Then calculate $\int_{C}^{}v dt$.

I know that this is a line integral. I tried to find its border.
For $z=0:$ I got  $\partial S: x^{2} + y^{4}=1$
I took $ x(t) = \cos t , y(t) = \sqrt{\sin t}$ so I got the parametric equation $\sigma (t) = (\cos t, \sqrt{\sin t}, 0) ,  t\in [0,2 \pi]$. Then I found  $\sigma ' (t)$ and $v(\sigma (t))$ and I calculated the integral. I found $0$ as an answer.
I had problems finding the border in this surface and I am not sure if I did it right. Are there another ways to find a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The surface $x^2+y^4+z^4=1$ is a closed surface. Are you referring to the portion of $x^2+y^4+z^4=1$ that's contained in the first quadrant?

Comment: @MatthewPilling That's the exercise. So $S$ is the whole surface. How can I see that this surface is a closed surface? So the answer is " The surface is closed, so there are no borders so the line integral should be $0$ " ?

Comment: It is a closed surface with no boundary. The way question asks you to do line integral around its border, that is just incorrect. There is no boundary and there is no curve defined and so a line integral is not possible. You cannot instead say that is equivalent to the line integral being zero.

Comment: @MathLover 
I totally agree with you but that was a question for a calculus test in a multiple choice exam. The possible answers were: $2, 2 \pi, \pi, 1, 0$ and OTHER ANSWER.

Comment: @MathLover How can I see that this surface is a closed one?

Comment: Pls check in Geogebra 3D or another online graphing tool.

Comment: @MathLover I have already tried. Geogebra 3D doesn't appear this graph.

Comment: Sometimes they do not render surfaces expressed in explicit form so write it in implicit form. Write $x = \sqrt{1-y^4-z^4}$ which is right half and write $x = - \sqrt{1-y^4-z^4}$ which is left half.